# Classpath problems

Tags: java, classpath

I have this directory structure (under Windows):
C:\JavaProjects\bin\debug\

In JavaProjects I have Test.java like this:

```
package debug;

public class Test{
    public void debug(String arg){
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

It has been compiled like this

```
javac -d bin Test.java
```

and in the debug directory now I have Test.class.

Then I create another class (also ConditionalCompilation.java in JavaProjects):

```
import debug.*;

public class ConditionalCompilation{
    public static void main(String[] args){
                Test a = new Test();
        a.debug("Test");
    }
}
```

Then, being in JavaProjects I write this:

```
C:\JavaProjects>javac -classpath .\bin ConditionalCompilation.java
```

No errors occur.

Now I try this:

```
C:\JavaProjects>java ConditionalCompilation
```

And get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: debug/Test
        at ConditionalCompilation.main(ConditionalCompilation.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: debug.Test
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Could you help me understand what I did wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you are trying to run and its dependency are on two different classpaths. `Test` class is rooted inside `bin`, wheras `ConditionalCompilation` class is rooted inside the parent directory.

One fix is to specify the dependency classpath explicitly.

```
java -classpath bin;. ConditionalCompilation
```

Another fix is to compile to and run from the `bin` directory.

```
javac -d .\bin -classpath .\bin ConditionalCompilation.java
cd bin
java ConditionalCompilation
```

Comment: Working. Thank you. But I can't understand anything. Why on two different classpaths?

Comment: @user3475946, Because your first compile line used the `-d` option to put the library on a different classpath.